# auto rotate image in loop

Tags: jquery, css

I want to rotate an image like with loader animation GIF.

I have `<img>` tag in html and my Jquery code is this:

```
setInterval(
    function () {
        $('#at_ex1').animate({rotate: '+=10deg'}, 0);
    },
    200
);
```

But is not work correctly. How to use this method in Jquery and CSS3 in loop.

Comment: i want to use this image rotation like loading page on own web site, i cant develop that code, ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle, I suspect it does exactly what you are after.

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 0):

var $elie = $("img"), degree = 0, timer;

```
function rotate() {

    $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
    $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        ++degree; rotate();
    },100);
}
```